# Find the largest sum from top to bottom in a depth tree

Tags: c#

I am looking to create a depth tree where each number is connected to two numbers on its left and right on the row below it.

Likewise, each number will be linked to the two numbers on its left and right on the row above it, or just one if it is at an end of its row.

Then I have to calculate the largest sum from top to bottom.

The numbers need to be added dynamically (by a text file) so I cannot add them individually. The format of the text file will look like the image below, taking carriage returns and spaces into consideration. The tree needs to look like this:

[image: Example of the tree]

I tried to do this a few different ways but I cannot seem to find the best way to do it. I tried 2 dimensional arrays and node trees but I am not proficient enough to do them. Below is a snippet of my Node Tree code that I tried. Please let me know if I need to do anything else here.

```
    public class Node
    {
        public int value;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public Node parent;

        public Node(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static Node NewNode(int value)
    {
        Node node = new Node(value);
        node.left = null;
        node.right = null;
        node.parent = null;
        return node;
    }

    public static void Insert(Node root, Node newNode)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            if (root.left == null)
            {
                root.left = newNode;
                newNode.parent = root;
            }
            else if(root.right == null) 
            {
                root.right = newNode;
                newNode.parent = root;
            }
            else
            {
                if (root.left.left == null)
                {
                    Insert(root.left, newNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    Insert(root.right, newNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Node GetTree(string filePath)
    {
        Node rootNode = null;

        string[] lines  = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        if (lines.Length == 0) return null;

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) return null;

            string[] values = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (values.Length == 0) return null;

            foreach (string value in values)
            {
                int number;
                if (!int.TryParse(value, out number)) return null;
            }

            if (rootNode == null)
            {
                rootNode = NewNode(int.Parse(values[0]));
            }
            else
            {
                Node node = rootNode;
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    Node newNode = NewNode(int.Parse(value));
                    Insert(node, newNode);
                    node = newNode;
                }
            }
        }

        return rootNode;
    }
```

Edit: The text file will look similar to this, expecting to have spaces and carriage returns:

```
3
7 6
2 4 9
1 4 8 2
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly how the number tree is calculated?

Comment: Thank you for your edits! Essentially the tree is supposed to go down the path and find the highest sum. In this instance, it's supposed to go 3+7, 3+6, then 3+7+2, 3+7+4, 3+6+4, 3+6+9, then onto the next line and on and on...lmao

Answer (score 0):

Use table for input.  Minus 1 is a node with no child.  The table could be rows in a csv file.

[image]

After some thinking I realize you can build the tree from an array of numbers.  You first create all the nodes in a list NODES with the values.  Then you link the list into the binary tree.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] data = { 3, 7, 6, 2, 4, 9, 1, 4, 8, 2 };
            Node root = Node.BuildTree(data);
        }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        int value { get; set; }
        Node left { get; set; }
        Node right { get; set; }
        static List<Node> nodes { get; set; }

        public static Node BuildTree(int[] input)
        {
            nodes = new List<Node>();
            foreach(int i in input)
            {
                Node node = new Node();
                node.left = null;
                node.right = null;
                node.value = i;
                nodes.Add(node);
            }
            Node root = nodes[0];
            int start = 0;
            int row = 0;
            while(start < nodes.Count)
            {
                int end = row + start;
                for (int i = start; i < Math.Min(end + 1, nodes.Count); i++)
                {
                    int col = i - start;
                    int leftChild = (end + 1 + col) < nodes.Count ? end + 1 + col : -1;
                    int rightChild = (end + 2 + col) < nodes.Count ? end + 2 + col : -1;
                    Console.WriteLine("row = {0}, col = {1}, left = {2}, right = {3}, start = {4}, end = {5}", row, col, leftChild, rightChild,start, end);
                    nodes[i].left = (leftChild == -1) ? null : nodes[leftChild];
                    nodes[i].right = (rightChild == -1) ? null : nodes[rightChild];
                }
                start = end + 1;
                row++;
            }    
            return root;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot use table, has to be a text file.

Comment: I said the input could come from a csv file.   Then put the csv data into a table.  When you create the binary tree you will need to look up the left and right child and the table will make it easier to locate the child nodes.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. If I'm not able to use a table/csv file, then I cannot do this method. The input will come from a text file that will look like this:

1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 0 
etc.

EDIT: Apparently I can't show how the text file will be, but basically it will follow what my picture shows.

Comment: The text file WILL look like the table I provided.  Each row contains commas to separate columns.  I've been doing problems like this for over 45 years.  The order of the columns may be different than what I show.  The table may show parent nodes instead of child nodes.

Comment: I apologize for being a little confused about what you mean. The question states that "text file contains a one-hundred depth tree in the same format as the given example". So it won't look like a table but more of a tree. Is that the same thing as what you posted?

Comment: You are correct.  My code below now takes the input as a single array and computers rows column numbers from the array.  The code can be easily converted to your input.  You need to process input in two passes. First pass creates the nodes into a list.  Second pass links the list into a tree.  When you build the tree you need to have both parent node and child node.  The input has parent and child on two different rows of the text file and makes it hard to link the parent to the child doing task in one pass.  So two passes are better.

Comment: So in this new script, I see that you are able to show the numbers in a table, but where does the calculation for highest sum in one path come in? And how do I extend this to take in a file and read the lines that will split per space and carriage return? Also I'm not entirely sure what the table is supposed to mean. It says left 1 right 2 but which one is the root that's supposed to show 3 then 7 and 6 as its children?

Comment: That is the task you are suppose to do.  You have to span the binary tree.  Left and right are the children node ID of the current row.

Comment: That is the task that I need help with ... Also the tree you have does not resemble how it is supposed to look. If row = 0 col = 0, then the parent needs to be 3, then row = 1 col = 0 left should be 7 not 3. I'm not sure you made this tree correctly.

Comment: You task is to span a binary tree, not an array of rows and columns.  The arrays and columns are just to load the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Structure of Graph.txt (Number of node, Weight of node, left number node, right number node):

```
(1,3,2,3)
(2,7,4,5)
(3,6,5,6)
(4,2,7,8)
(5,4,8,9)
(6,9,9,10)
(7,1,,)
(8,4,,)
(9,8,,)
(10,2,,)
```

Code:

```
public class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public string LeftId { get; set; }
        public string RightId { get; set; }
        public Node Left { get; set; }
        public Node Right { get; set; }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var graphDefinition = File.ReadAllText("Graph.txt");
            var regex = new Regex(@"\((?<Id>\d*),(?<Weight>\d*),(?<Left>\d*),(?<Right>\d*)\)");

            var nodes = new List<Node>();

            foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(graphDefinition))
            {
                nodes.Add(new Node
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(match.Groups["Id"].Value),
                    Weight = int.Parse(match.Groups["Weight"].Value),
                    LeftId = match.Groups["Left"].Value,
                    RightId = match.Groups["Right"].Value
                });
            }

            if (!nodes.Any())
                return;

            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.LeftId))
                    node.Left = nodes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == int.Parse(node.LeftId));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.RightId))
                    node.Right = nodes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == int.Parse(node.RightId));

            }

            var root = nodes.First();

            Depth(root, 0);

            Console.WriteLine($"result calculation: {CalculatedMax}");
        }

        private static int CalculatedMax = int.MinValue;

        private static void Depth(Node node, int currentSum)
        {
            if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null)
            {
                CalculatedMax = Math.Max(CalculatedMax, currentSum + node.Weight);
                return;
            }

            Depth(node.Left, currentSum + node.Weight);
            Depth(node.Right, currentSum + node.Weight);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if the text file looks more like this

1  
2 3  
4 5 6

Comment: OK I suck at editing, but basically first line will have 1 number, then next line will have 2 numbers, etc.

Comment: You did not provide an example file, so I proposed my own format, which unambiguously describes the proposed tree example. If the file has a specific format, then this information must also be added to the description. In my answer, if the regex doesn't match any data in the file, the program will simply exit.

Comment: Understandably. The file would look like the example picture I had above. The code has to create the tree then do the calculation based on all available paths then find the highest sum.

Comment: Hey @Maxim sorry to bring you back into this. Couple questions, how do I add the space and carriage return to the regex list? Also how does the ID/Weight/childID work and what are they meant to do? With my set up, I just have a parent, two children, and a value.

Comment: I used http://regexstorm.net/reference to build regex expressions.

Comment: I see, and what about the IDs? What are their purposes?

Comment: This is an identifier of the node. In the general case (when the number of levels is not limited), you need to somehow identify each node. The number with the node may not be unique.